# How to transfer image into vector using resnet50 and ImageDataGenerator?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision

I don't want my model to learn, just give me embeddings. I have dataframe with images names in one of it's columns and directory with images. There are  1000 unique images in directory and 5031 lines in dataframe, so images names in dataframe are not unique.

So I use pre-tarined resnet using tf.keras:

```
resnet_model = Sequential()

model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet',
                         include_top=False,
                         input_shape=(224, 224, 3),
                         pooling='max')

resnet_model.add(model)
resnet_model.add(Flatten())

for layer in resnet_model.layers:
    layer.trainable=False
```

specifically set layers to be untrainable. Then make data generator using tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
train_gen_flow = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
        dataframe=my_data_frame,
        directory=my_directory,
        x_col='image',
        y_col='baned',
        target_size=(224, 224),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='raw',
        seed=12345)
```

And ask model to predict

```
feature_list = resnet_model.predict(train_gen_flow, 1)
```

I expected to get identical vectors for same images since my layers are untrainable. But I get different vectors.

Comment: you code is not distinctable between `pytorch` and `tensorflow`. Edit it and use appropriate tag.

Comment: @rafathasan PyTorch does not have an ImageDataGenerator function, this is Keras.

Comment: Are you sure it's the same image run twice? It's been a while since I've use the `ImageDataGenerator` API, but if I remember correctly, it generates the next image. So if you're asking it to predict the same index of images twice, it won't be the same.

Comment: @ZWang but how to generate same images?

Comment: @Herzshprung You could load the image through another pipeline, custom written if you wanted to, using numpy. Remember, to expand dims to match `(1,224,224,3)`.

Comment: Just pass a array and check, ex - resnet_model.predict(tf.ones((10, 224, 224, 3)))